# Create mobile application

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-phone, mobile-application

I am an .net developer and i want to have some guidance to make a new mobile application.

My application must be cross-plateform (Windows mobile 6, Windows Phone 7 and later, iOS, Android).

Have the capability to work offline with a local database (Some information may be collected without the user having access to the network)

Have the capability to use webservices to send or get data collected.

So what is the bests tools or the bests plateforms i have to use to make this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Phone Gap](http://phonegap.com/)
You can develop in html5, javascript and css. 
It will work on each platform [Phone Gap](http://phonegap.com/) supports.

Comment: Phone Gap does not support Windows Mobile 6, which is one of his starting requirements.

Comment: i.e. why I mentioned the platforms it supports. And this is the closest way to his scenario, I guess.

Comment: You can use phone gap on WM6 BUT have to use a better browser than the one coming with WM6. For example you may use the zetaKey HTML5 browser. Using a HTML5 solution will give you cross platform compatibility as long as you can provide the environment.HTML5 supports offline storage and data sync.

Answer (score 0):

Getting something that supports WinMo 6, Windows Phone, iOS and Android is tricky.  You will not be able to have one code base for the UI.  That's just not going to happen.  If you use C#, you can create a pretty common code base for the business logic all the way up through presenters/controllers/viewmodels using a mix of Visual Studio (you'll need both 2008 for WinMo and 2012 or 2013 for Phone) and [Xamarin's tools](http://xamarin.com/) (for iOS and Android), then you can create the UI layer that is appropriate for each target with those same tools.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Phone 7, 8, iOS, Android you can go for Xamarin. This platform support Portable Class Libraries. These libraries work on all these platforms. 
However, for Windows Phone 6, you'll need to write most of the logic separately. Understand main point here: WM supports till .NET Framework 3.5. For others, using Xamarin, you can take benefit from .NET 4.5 (Async/Await, etc...)
There is also an option of file-linking in Xamarin. Using which, you can maximize the code-sharing. 
I'm doubtful about using PhoneGap on WM.